# ALSA - Which channel is sampled first

Tags: audio, buffer, alsa

I have two channels of analog audio (left and right) connected to ALSA device and I let soundcard do the sampling.

The result is one digital stream of interleaved audio. My problem occurs when i try to play them. Once  these channels are swapped and once not. It seems like it depends on which channel was sampled first or on time when the playing begun.

To clarify my situation:

I have three sound cards: Cards A and B are sampling analog audio, then I send one digitalized audio channel from each to card C, thru LAN. So for example I send only left channel from card A to card C and simultaneously I send right channel from card B to card C.

On card C, I reasemble those data packets to interleaved stream. So i take first sample (which is from card A) and then sample from card B. This way i can play this buffer like interleaved audio. Card C is then playing data from this buffer. Given that soundcard starts playing samples to left channel, then i should have no problem. But sometimes it swaps the channels and I can't figure out why.

I'm controlling this all with ARM processor.

Is there a way i can access ALSA's internal frame buffer or how to say what in the stream would be played first ?

It leads to another question, how does for example in wav format the player knows what part of data is for left and what for right channel ?

Comment: Recording and playback always must start with the first (left) channel. My crystal ball tells me you are using one of those embedded devices with crappy hardware and a buggy driver.

Comment: The odd thing is that it seems like soundcard is sometimes starting reading the buffer for right channel, instead of left. @CL - Your Palantir is not so away from reality, we are using CS4202-JQZ. Do you think that this can be crappy HW ?

Comment: What is the AC'97 controller?

Comment: @CL I'm not sure what u asking about, but AC97 is standart for audio codec. CS4202 is compliant with this standart.

Comment: An AC'97 bus is a connection between two chips, the codec and the controller. The CS4202 is the codec. What is your controller?

Comment: I'm controlling with ARM (ATMEL AT91SAM9263).

Comment: [Told you so](https://www.google.com/search?q=alsa+atmel+left+right).

Comment: Thank you so much, but i'm now confused more than before :) It seems that this bug is 4 years old. What are you suggesting? Patch the driver, use another controller? I'm noobie in this.

Comment: I know less about Atmel chips than you.

Answer (score 0):

WAV is rather easy: channels are stored in the LSB-order in which they appear in `dwChannelMask`, (a bitmask listing any of the speakers present). So if the bitmask is 0x3, bits 0 and 1 are set, and you'll have two audio streams in the WAV: the first is left (bitmask 0x1) and the second is right (bitmask 0x2). If the bitmask was 0xB, there would be a third audio stream, a bass channel (0x8).

ALSA is Linux Audio and that's just not as well designed. There's no such thing as **the** internal ALSA streambuffer.